# Translation of "to have consequences"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What is the best Latin translation of

> This will have consequences

as in "*what has transpired will affect the future*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very literal translation **consequentias habet** would appear to be acceptable in modern Latin (e.g. it occurs in [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=dmHidOxzn_oC&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=consequentias+habet&source=bl&ots=tqNOG7NCw3&sig=ACfU3U1xp0LdBN0yEwpwwxeZSA-0OTRwSw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjivff3zKLsAhXCzKQKHRfrAcgQ6AEwB3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=consequentias%20habet&f=false) published by the Pontifical University Gregoriana in 1948).

Comment: I don't think "consequentias habere" is a very good translation. I read a few selections from the book, and it seems pretty clear that it's a literal calque-style translation from a modern Romance language. That was a common style for manuals of this kind, but probably shouldn't be recommended under normal circumstances. (For reference, "consequentia" seems to be a post-classical term--it only occurs in Cicero, I think, as the participle for *consequor*.)

Comment: It's certainly not classical Latin, true, which is why I specified that it would appear to be acceptable in modern Latin (as in the language of the Vatican).